# Import sql to default db ddev

Tags: sql, mysql, import

I'm confused a little bit about how I can import a custom .sql file into the default db as soon as it gets ready.
I tried putting an import command under .ddev/commands/web but didn't work out.

Thanks in advance

I've added a .sh file under .ddev/commands/web with the following:

`mysql -u db -pdb db < /var/www/html/sql/my.sql`

If I run the above command when I create the container it works fine but it doesn't auto load when I make the container for first time.
I'm trying to find a way to load that file after the creation of the container.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why the import command is not working is because the `.ddev/commands/web` file is only executed when you start your project with the `ddev start` command. If you want to import the custom .sql file after the container is created, you need to use a different method.

One way to do this is to use the `ddev exec`command. The `ddev exec` command allows you to run a command inside the container. to import the custom .sql file, you would run the following command:
`ddev exec sh -c 'mysql -u db -pdb db < /var/www/html/sql/my.sql'`

This will run the `mysql` command inside the container and import the custom .sql file

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I wasn't clear enough, I meant that I want to be executed the first time that I will run ddev start not afterwards.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).